# subsetting closed values in a column based on binary column in a data frame by R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 85 rows and 35 columns which is sorted based on age column, like below:

```
No  Gender  Age
1   F   5.8
2   F   5.9
3   F   6
4   M   6.2
5   F   7
6   F   7.2
7   M   7.4
8   M   7.8
9   M   7.9
10  M   8.1
11  F   8.3
12  F   8.6
13  M   8.9
14  M   9
15  F   9.2
16  F   9.3
```

I need to subset **closest** ages in different genders. like below:

```
No  Gender  Age
1   F   6
2   M   6.2
3   F   7.2
4   M   7.4
5   M   8.1
6   F   8.3
7   F   8.6
8   M   8.9
9   M   9
10  F   9.2
```

Comment: Your conditions are not clear. What do you mean by 'closest'?

Comment: @Sotos: The ages which are near together, for example want rwos 3 and 4 not 1 and 4. 6 and 6.2 are closer than 5.8 and 6.2.

Comment: ahh...ok. I get it

Comment: I am not sure if I got what you mean, but it is sorted like the example and the max value is not important, just closed age is important.

Comment: the max value for female is 13.3 and for male is 18.3

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got this. It was surprisingly difficult, and maybe someone else will be able to come up with a more elegant solution, but here's what I got:

```
df <- data.frame(No=c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,16L),Gender=c('F','F','F','M','F','F','M','M','M','M','F','F','M','M','F','F'),Age=c(5.8,5.9,6,6.2,7,7.2,7.4,7.8,7.9,8.1,8.3,8.6,8.9,9,9.2,9.3),stringsAsFactors=F);
mls <- df$Gender=='M';
mages <- df$Age[mls];
fages <- df$Age[!mls];
fisLower <- findInterval(mages,fages);
TOL <- 1e-5;
fisClosest <- fisLower+ifelse(fisLower==0L | fisLower<length(fages) & mages-fages[replace(fisLower,fisLower==0L,NA)]>fages[fisLower+1L]-mages+TOL,1L,0L);
mis <- unname(tapply(seq_along(mages),fisClosest,function(is) is[which.min(abs(mages[is]-fages[fisClosest[is[1L]]]))]));
fis <- unique(fisClosest);
df[sort(c(which(mls)[mis],which(!mls)[fis])),];
##    No Gender Age
## 3   3      F 6.0
## 4   4      M 6.2
## 6   6      F 7.2
## 7   7      M 7.4
## 10 10      M 8.1
## 11 11      F 8.3
## 12 12      F 8.6
## 13 13      M 8.9
## 14 14      M 9.0
## 15 15      F 9.2
```

Explanation of variables:

- `df` The input data.frame.
- `mls` "male logicals": A logical vector representing which elements of `df$Gender` are male.
- `mages` "male ages": The subset of `df$Age` for male rows.
- `fages` "female ages": The subset of `df$Age` for female rows.
- `fisLower` "female indexes lower": For each element of `mages`, this has the index into `fages` of the female age that lies just below (or possibly equal to) the male age. This could be zero if `fages` has no ages below the element of `mages`. Hence this vector is "parallel" to `mages`, meaning it's the same length and the elements correspond to each other.
- `TOL` "tolerance" This was a necessary annoyance to prevent spurious floating-point comparison errors in the following statement.
- `fisClosest` "female indexes closest" This is a simple transformation of `fisLower`. Basically, we must add `1L` to each element of `fisLower` if the corresponding element of `mages` is actually closer to the *subsequent* element of `fages` (the "upper" one) rather than the one pointed to by the corresponding element of `fisLower` (the "lower" one). This must be done for two cases: (1) zero elements of `fisLower`, and (2) where the element of `fisLower` points to a non-last element of `fages` and the element of `mages` is actually closer to the subsequent element of `fages`.
- `mis` "male indexes" First of all, understand that `fisClosest` may contain duplicates if multiple male ages have the same female age as their closest, IOW there is no other female age closer to that male age, for all of them. For each of these conflicts, we must find the one male age that is closest to the female age from the set of male ages. This requires a vector aggregation for which `tapply()` is appropriate. We group by `fisClosest`, passing `mages` indexes into the lambda, where we call `which.min()` on the absolute differences between the ages to get the winning male age, and return its index.
- `fis` "female indexes" This is simply the unique set of indexes into `fages` which we need to select from `df`; we get this from `fisClosest` by removing duplicates.

At this point we can finally convert from `mages` and `fages` indexes (`mis` and `fis`) to `df` row indexes by indexing the appropriate respective polarities of `mls`. After combining and sorting the two index sets, we can finally index `df` to get the required output.

---

**Original (Incorrect) Solution**

It looks like you want the first and last row of each run length, excepting the first and last row of the entire data.frame. Here's one way to achieve that:

```
df <- data.frame(No=c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,16L),Gender=c('F','F','F','M','F','F','M','M','M','M','F','F','M','M','F','F'),Age=c(5.8,5.9,6,6.2,7,7.2,7.4,7.8,7.9,8.1,8.3,8.6,8.9,9,9.2,9.3),stringsAsFactors=F);
x <- cumsum(rle(df$Gender)$lengths); df2 <- df[unique(c(rbind(c(1L,x[-length(x)]+1L),x))),];
df2 <- df2[-c(1L,nrow(df2)),]; ## remove first and last row from original data.frame
df2;
##    No Gender Age
## 3   3      F 6.0
## 4   4      M 6.2
## 5   5      F 7.0
## 6   6      F 7.2
## 7   7      M 7.4
## 10 10      M 8.1
## 11 11      F 8.3
## 12 12      F 8.6
## 13 13      M 8.9
## 14 14      M 9.0
## 15 15      F 9.2
```

I think you missed the `F 7.0` row in your expected output; other than that, this gets the same set of rows. If you want to fix up `No` to be sequential from 1, you can run `df2$No <- seq_len(nrow(df2))`. Ditto for the row names (with `rownames(df2)` on the LHS).

Comment: thank you for your help but It does not help me. I need the output like that I wrote. just  closest age in each gender.

Comment: Question for you: Can you take a look at `data.frame(Gender=c('F','M','M','M','F'),Age=c(5,11,12,13,14))` and tell me what the expected output would be for that test case?

Comment: the result will be: data.frame(Gender=c('M','F'),Age=c(13,14))